# Modify object's keys without creating new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have following input:

```
{
  foo: 4,
  bar: 3
}
```

I want to modify the keys of this object to get:

```
{
  x_foo_y: 4,
  x_bar_y: 3
}
```

Is it possible to modify the object without creating new one ? (jQuery available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you just add the new keys and remove the old ones:

```
obj.x_foo_y = obj.foo;
delete obj.foo;
obj.x_bar_y = obj.bar;
delete obj.bar;
```

Note that on some engines (notably V8 in Chrome), this will [impact the performance](http://jsperf.com/dictionary-mode-example) of the object. If you don't need to actually *remove* the properties, you could just set their values to `undefined`:

```
obj.x_foo_y = obj.foo;
obj.foo = undefined;
obj.x_bar_y = obj.bar;
obj.bar = undefined;
```

Which won't have the impact (it's the `delete` that makes V8 put the object into "dictionary mode," which is much slower than V8's normal compiled class mode).

If you wanted to do this for all "own" properties in an object:

```
var key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj["x" + key + "y"] = obj[key];
        delete obj[key]; // Or obj[key] = undefined if that's okay for your use case
    }
}
```

Comment: The add-property-after-literal doesn't trigger the "dictionary mode"?

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a loop ? Because all of the keys will gain the same prefix/suffix.

Comment: thats a great insight.

Comment: @user2864740: No, V8's JIT creates a derived class with the additional properties.

Comment: @hsz: Sure, just use `for-in` to loop through the keys, then use brackets notation and a string for the property names.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Silly me - that's right. Thanks !

Comment: Setting to undefined doesn't remove it from the object.

Comment: @Scimonster: Right. Which is why I said *"If you don't need to actually remove the properties...."* and *"...if that's okay for your use case..."*

Comment: 'K, didn't notice that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the keys and then delete the old ones.

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 4,
  bar: 3
};
obj.x_foo_y = obj.foo;
obj.x_bar_y = obj.bar;
delete obj.foo;
delete obj.bar;
alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: Ooh! Code snippet! I didn't realize they'd gone live. :-)