# Is it possible to change property name of Json?

Tags: javascript

I wanna know if it is possible to change the property name of a json

For example I have `{"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737}`

and I want to change lon with lng  , so like this `{"lat":27.4924,"lng":77.6737}`

Comment: `foo.lng = foo.lon; delete foo.lon;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key) and [Modify object's keys without creating new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929400)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`delete operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```js
let obj = {"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737}
obj.lng = obj.lon;
delete obj.lon;

console.log(obj)
```

One  more way is to use [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let obj = {"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737, 'xyz':2}
let {lon:lng,...rest} = obj
let obj1 = {...rest,lng}

console.log(obj1)
```

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) also you can do

```js
let obj = {"lat":27.4924,"lon":77.6737}

let op = Object.keys(obj).reduce((op,cur)=>{
  if(cur == 'lon'){
    op['lng'] = obj[cur]
  } else {
    op[cur] = obj[cur]
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: is this possible to do over array of json ?

Answer (score 0):

A funny way to do it would be to stringify the json and replace the string.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsn).replace("lon", "lng"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. You assign the value of old property to new property and delete old one. using `delete`. I have created a function for that

```js
let obj = {"lat":27.4924,"log":77.6737}
function changePropName(obj,oldName,newName){
  obj[newName] = obj[oldName];
  delete obj[oldName];
}
changePropName(obj,'log','newName');
console.log(obj)
```